# How can I turn off the message "The media contains digital photo", in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, photo-management

I have a FAT partition on my system for storage purposes, and from a time to now I'm seeing this message in Nautilus:

> The media contains digital photo

There is any way to turn it off?

Comment: You might be interested in [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588601).

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 11.10 I have not found a way to disable this behaviour using a setting. However, I found that by simply de-installing shotwell, the message also goes away.

Comment: You need to uninstall *all* photo-organising tools. Shotwell, gThumb, etc...

Comment: goodbye shotwell!

Answer (score 3):

No, it is impossible by design to turn it off. A request to allow users to [get rid of the media suggestions bar](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587516) was closed as "won't fix".