# HP Envy Beats Edition can play CDs, but not DVDs

Tags: 11.04, dvd, hp

After a fresh install, and various other tests (troubleshooting), I have concluded that my laptop (an HP Envy 14 - Beats Edtion) will not play DVDs, however it will play CDs.

When I first got the laptop, up until recently it played DVDs perfectly, I doubt there is a hardware issue sees as it loads the DVDs and can view the files in them, but not play them, as well as read and work with CDs perfectly.

Was there an update or something of the like that may have caused this? If so, is there a fix? I typically use this laptop 's HDMI out with my TV as a DVD player... so it would be very beneficial if there was a solution to this problem.

There was a similar issue with the touchpad that there was a fix for... so I'm hoping that this is something similar

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47542/how-turn-off-the-message-the-media-contains-digital-photo-message-in-nautilus/47544

Answer (score 2):

[image]- Install VLC

Open Synaptic application
Click on System -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager.
In Settings -> Repositories, make sure you have an universe repository activated.

Search for vlc and install it, as well as vlc-plugin-pulse. You may also want to install mozilla-plugin-vlc.

If you are interested in streaming or transcoding, you should additionnally install libavcodec-extra-52 from a multiverse repository.
Command line way

You need to check that a universe mirror is listed in your /etc/apt/sources.list file.

```
% sudo apt-get update
% sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```